# Turns ratio of multi winding transformer

Tags: transformer

Hi can anyone let me know what is the overall turns ratio of the transformer shown in image below as i was confused

[image: Transformer]

[image: Turns Ratio]

Comment: *The overall turns ratio* — such thing does not exist. You have to look at the individual windings. You may even leave 3-5 unconnected and use this as a 24V←→12V transformer.

Comment: What are you confused about? The turns ratio of the primary winding (3-5) to each secondary winding is as shown in the data you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could describe the overall turns ratio as: 9.25:2(C.T.):1(C.T.), where the first number is 3-5, the second is 8-10 with centre tap 9 and the third is 12-14 with centre tap 13

Comment: Do you know what could be an appropriate model for a center tapped transformer? I have my question here: [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498095/center-tapped-transformer-equivalent-circuit-model/498163?noredirect=1#comment1272033_498163)

Answer (score 2):

You can only have a turns ratio between a pair of coils. You can't have an overall term ratio when several coils are involved unless you connect pairs of coils to form one coil.

For example, 8 - 9 and 9 -10 are series connected and the combined turns ratio would be 9.25:1 + 9.25:1= 9.25:2 between 8 and 10.

This should be clear as doubling the number of turns will double the output voltage.